# Linux Command to get fields from CSV files

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, cut

In csv files on Linux server,  I have thousands of rows in below csv format

```
0,20221208195546466,9,200,Above as:2|RAN34f2fb:HAER:0|RAND8365b2bca763:FON:0|RANDa7a5f964900b:ION:0|
```

I need to get output from all the files on below format (2nd field ie 20221208195546466  and 5th field but value after `Above as:` and before first |  ie 2 in above example )

output :

```
20221208195546466 , 2
```

Can anyone help me with linux command ?

Edit :

my attempts

I tried but it give field 5th value. How to add field 2 as well ?

```
cat *.csv | cut -d, -f5|cut -d'|' -f1|cut -d':' -f2|
```

EDIT : sorted result

Now I am using this command (based on Dave Pritlove answer ) awk -F'[,|:]' '{print $2", "$6}' file.csv. However, I have one more query, If I have to sort the output based on $6 ( value 2 in your example ) then how can i do it ?  I want result should be displayed in sorted order based on 2nd output field.
for ex :

> 20221208195546366, 20
>
> 20221208195546436, 16
>
> 20221208195546466, 5
>
> 2022120819536466, 2

Comment: Can anyone please help ? Why close votes ? i tried with cat and cut but couldnt do it

Comment: *"Why close votes?"*: please see [How much research efffort is expected of SO users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This has been asked tons of times, you must be able to find some questions about this, if you cant get it to work, [edit] your question to show your attempt(s)

Comment: Please see my edit to understand my attempt

Comment: I tried 
cat *.csv | awk -F',' '{gsub(/Total ts:/,""); gsub(/\|.*/, ""); print($2, $5)}'

Comment: please update the question with your `awk` attempt(s); also, your `awk` code references a string `Total ts:` but no such string exists in your sample input; if the string in question can vary across rows (eg, `Total ts:` vs `Above as:`) then please update the question to show a few rows of input that display this difference in strings; also, your expected output shows a space on each side of the `,` ... is this what you really want or should those spaces not exist (as is the case in the input)?

Comment: See [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gnu awk` allows multiple field separators to be set, allowing you to delimit each record at `,`, `|`, and `:` at the same time. Thus, the following will fish out the required fields from `file.csv`:

```
awk -F'[,|:]' '{print $2", "$6}' file.csv
```

Tested on the single record example:

```
echo "0,20221208195546466,9,200,Above as:2|RAN34f2fb:HAER:0|RAND8365b2bca763:FON:0|RANDa7a5f964900b:ION:0|" | awk -F'[,|:]' '{print $2", "$6}'
```

output:

```
20221208195546466, 2
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Use `OFS=", "`, and then `print $2, $6`

Comment: Thanks.  I have one more query, If I have to sort the output based on $6 ( value 2 in your example ) then how can i do it ?  I want result should be displayed in sorted order based on 2nd output field. 
for ex : 

20221208195546366, 20
20221208195546436, 16
20221208195546466, 5
2022120819536466, 2

Comment: apply `sort` to the output file. Lots of examples available by searching, I'd probably try `sort -t, -nk2 outfile.csv` (-t sets the delimeter to comma, n forces numerical interpretation, k2 specifies 2nd field).

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- starting string of the 5th comma-delimited field can vary from line to line (ie, not known before hand)
- the item of interest in the 5th comma-delimited field occurs between the first `:` and the first `|`

Sample data:

```
$ cat test.csv
0,20221208195546466,9,200,Above as:2|RAN34f2fb:HAER:0|RAND8365b2bca763:FON:0|RANDa7a5f964900b:ION:0|
1,20230124123456789,10,1730,Total ts:7|stuff:HAER:0|morestuff:FON:0|yetmorestuff:ION:0|
```

One `awk` approach:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }                    # define input/output field delimiter as ","
      { split($5,a,"[:|]")              # split 5th field on dual delimiters ":" and "|", store results in array a[]
        print $2,a[2]                   # print desired items to stdout
      }
' test.csv
```

This generates:

```
20221208195546466,2
20230124123456789,7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk -F',' '{gsub(/Above as:/,""); gsub(/\|.*/, ""); print($2, $5)}'
```

Probably need to adopt regexp a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You might change `:` to `,` and `|` to `,` then extract 2nd and 6th field using `cut` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
0,20221208195546466,9,200,Above as:2|RAN34f2fb:HAER:0|RAND8365b2bca763:FON:0|RANDa7a5f964900b:ION:0|
```

then

```
tr ':|' ',,' < file.txt | cut --delimiter=',' --output-delimiter=' , ' --fields=2,6
```

gives output

```
20221208195546466 , 2
```

Explanation: `tr` translates i.e. replace `:` using `,` and replace `|` using `,` then I inform `cut` that delimiter in input is `,` output delimiter is , encased in spaces (as stipulated by your desired output) and want 2th and 6th column (not 5th, as it is now `Above as`)

*(tested using GNU coreutils 8.30)*